# Send a binary file via Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I want to send an http POST request with a binary data from a file.
I get a successful server respond when I do it via postman->Body->Binary->Choose file. see image:

[image]

But I can not figure out how to do it via Angular HttpClient. How can I finish the following:

```
set processImage(event) {
    console.log(event);
    let files: FileList = event.target.files;
    let file = files[0]; 
    //send the file as a binary via httpClient
    ....
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Here's the code for future reference for anyone in need:

```
processImage(event) {
    console.log(event);
    let files: FileList = event.target.files;
    let file : File = files[0];
    this.http.post(URL, file).subscribe(
      (r)=>{console.log('got r', r)}
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution (y)

Answer (score 0):

For Sending binary Data in Angular you can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)
example :

```
let file = event.target.files[0];
let url = 'your url';
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myfile", file);

this.http.post(url,formData).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    console.log('response', res)
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks, it's made my day, it's perfect if request Header has Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>

Comment: `formData.append("myfile", formData)` should be `formData.append("myfile", file)`?
Also, http.post(url, body) should have url as the first argument?

Comment: why about a binary data with octet-stream type content  insted of formdata

Comment: This is precisely incorrect.  Sending binary is totally different than sending form data, which requires at least one key/value pair.  For example, when uploading to S3 using a presigned URL you must send in binary and this will not work.  You can simply look at Postman and notice they are totally different bodies.